# Spark pairwise differences within groups

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a spark dataframe, for the sake of argument lets take it to be:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
    Seq(("a",1,2),("a",1,4),("b",5,6),("b",10,2),("c",1,1))
  ).toDF("id","x","y")
+---+---+---+
| id|  x|  y|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  1|  2|
|  a|  1|  4|
|  b|  5|  6|
|  b| 10|  2|
|  c|  1|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

I would like to compute all pairwise differences between entries in the dataframe with the same id and output the result to another dataframe. For a small dataframe I can accomplish this by:

```
df.crossJoin(
  df.select(
    (df.columns.map(x=>col(x).as("_"+x))):_*)
  ).where(
    col("id")===col("_id")
  ).select(
    col("id"),
    (col("x")-col("_x")).as("dx"),
    (col("y")-col("_y")).as("dy")
  )
+---+---+---+
| id| dx| dy|
+---+---+---+
|  c|  0|  0|
|  b|  0|  0|
|  b| -5|  4|
|  b|  5| -4|
|  b|  0|  0|
|  a|  0|  0|
|  a|  0| -2|
|  a|  0|  2|
|  a|  0|  0|
+---+---+---+
```

However, for large dataframes this isn't a reasonable approach as the crossJoin will mostly produce data that will be discarded by the subsequent where clause.

I'm still pretty new to spark and groupBy seemed like a natural place to start looking, but I can't figure out how to accomplish this using groupBy. Any help would be welcome.

I would eventually like to remove redundancy, for instance in:

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("idx",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df.crossJoin(
  df.select(
    (df.columns.map(x=>col(x).as("_"+x))):_*)
  ).where(
    col("id")===col("_id") && col("idx") < col("_idx")
  ).select(
    col("id"),
    (col("x")-col("_x")).as("dx"),
    (col("y")-col("_y")).as("dy")
  )

+---+---+---+
| id| dx| dy|
+---+---+---+
|  b| -5|  4|
|  a|  0| -2|
+---+---+---+
```

But if its easier to accomplish this with redundancy, then I can live with that.

This is not an uncommon transformation to perform in ML so I thought something out of MLlib might be appropriate, but again I haven't found anything there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achived via inner join, result the same as expected:

```
df.alias("left").join(df.alias("right"),"id")
  .select($"id",
      ($"left.x"-$"right.x").alias("dx"),
      ($"left.y"-$"right.y").alias("dy"))
```

Comment: well that was an embarrassing oversight on my part.